# How can i set the length of output from "for loop" in javascript ? based from the input, not how many times loop will execute

Tags: javascript, for-loop

In this case, i want to display the length of output from the user input using "for loop".

```
let value = []

const getTotalDisp = (input) => {
    for(let i=1; i<input; i++){
        if(i%2===0){
            value.push(i)
        }
    }
    return value
}

console.log(getTotalDisp (10))
```

this would be display :

> [2,4,6,8]

and what i expected the output display is if user input 10, then the output length must be ten numbers like :

> [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20]

How should i do to set the condition of it ? i tried to add some condition before "for loop" like this :

```
let value = []

const getTotalDisp = (input) => {
  if(value.length<input){
    for(let i=1; i<input; i++){
        if(i%2===0){
            value.push(i)
        }
    }
    return value
  }
}

console.log(getTotalDisp (10))
```

but it doesn't work. Could anyobdy help me to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: The comparison does not have to be `i`? Use the length. `for(let i=1; value.length<input; i++){`

Answer (score 1):

Set the loop condition as `value.length < input`.

```js
const getTotalDisp = (input) => {
  const value = [];
  for (let i = 1; value.length < input; i++)
    if (i % 2 === 0) value.push(i);
  return value
}
console.log(getTotalDisp(10));
```

Of course, in this case, it is easy to calculate the actual number to stop at for there to be a certain number of even values.

```js
const getTotalDisp = (input) => {
  const value = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= input; i++) value.push(i * 2);
  return value;
}
console.log(getTotalDisp(10));
```

Alternatively, with `Array#map`:

```js
const getTotalDisp = input => [...Array(input)].map((_, i) => (i + 1) * 2);
console.log(getTotalDisp(10));
```